# Can I view WebGL content on an Asus laptop with shutter glasses?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, 3d, webgl

Can I view WebGl content, ([example this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_ctm_materials.html)) on an Asus G74S laptop, with **3D shutter glasses**?

I'm using Chrome, which supports WebGL, but how can I tell OpenGL to render it differently?

Is it possible at all?

Comment: What kind of glasses? Sunglasses? :) Anaglyph glasses? Polarized glasses? Shutter glasses?

Comment: @slhck :) with 3D vision glasses, which comes with the laptop. a.k.a Shutter glasses.

Answer (score 0):

well if the app itself contains 3d feature, and your screen is 3d ready, and your GA can run such things, then yes. Why do you just try?

Comment: I tried a lot. I think somewhere there should be a settings, or something, which change the rendereing, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just some Nvidia hardware and Firefox and for YouTube, as far as I know: http://www.0xdeadbeef.com/weblog/2011/05/bringing-the-first-3d-html5-video-to-the-web-with-firefox-nvidia-and-youtube/

But look at this presentation for the rest of us: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cars_anaglyph.html